# Determine if method or member can be protected or private

Tags: c++, gcc

It is possible to check (for example by gcc) which methods or members can be moved to protected or private section?

Comment: You can move all of them to private and then check for errors thrown by the compiler. Then, based on the error information, you can move them one by one to protected, so derived classes will be able to access them.

Comment: Do you mean, which methods of the public API are unused (and hence can be made private)?

Comment: It should be the API which dictates which method should be public.

Comment: May be some static analyzers can do it. I'm not aware of any.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the following part of code:

```
class foo{
    protected:
        void foo_method_1(){};
        int foo_member_var;
};

class bar : public foo{
    void bar_method_1(){
        foo_method_1();
    }
};
```

If you want to determine which members and methods of the foo class can be private, you have to move all of them to the private section. So it will look like this:

```
class foo{
    private:
        void foo_method_1(){};
        int foo_member_var;
};
...
```

Now it won't compile, here's the first error thrown by GCC:

```
prog.cpp:5:8: error: 'void foo::foo_method_1()' is private
   void foo_method_1(){};
```

From that you know, that you have to move the foo_method_1 to the protected section. So it will look like this:

```
class foo{
    private:
        int foo_member_var;
    protected:
        void foo_method_1(){};
};
...
```

Now it will compile. You have to repeat this process for every single method and member in your class. For public section you can do it in the same way as described above.

Comment: I know this approach, but it is time consuming.

Comment: @marcin Unfortunately it is. In order to speed it up you can compile your code like this: `gcc -o foo bar.cpp 2> errors` and then `cat errors | grep "is private"`. You will get a list of functions which can't be private. Then you can move all of them at once to protected.

Answer (score 2):

**You can't do this programmatically, no. *And that's actually a good thing.***

Sure, you could create a tool that integrated with a C++ parser, then — one-by-one — made certain members functions `private` and left any there that didn't cause an error in your program.

But, in order to do that, **your entire program would need to be visible to that tool**. Maybe if you have a simple project that's not a problem, but **if you're writing a library that's literally impossible**.

Even if you could do it, your resulting class design would be an absolute mess. **Only a human programmer knows which parts of the API are designed for public consumption or not**, and that's not always the same as which parts of the API are *currently being consumed*.

Stick to the manual approach, but don't just replicate the way the machine would do it, randomly guessing based on what compiles and what does not compile. Use your brain and your memory of what this class is supposed to do, to determine which functions should be `public` and which should not.

Ideally, **try to get it right when you're first designing your class**! You should be spending far more time designing your program than actually programming it, lest you very quickly end up with maintenance nightmares like this.

Answer (score 1):

No. The compiler sees your **code**, not your **design**.